# Adding OR statements to a scope in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, named-scope

Is it possible to add OR statements to a scope argument in a rails model something like

```
scope :west_coast, where(:st => "CA" || "WA" || "OR")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is really how to make an sql `WHERE ... IN` statement using activerecord:

```
scope :west_coast, where(st: %w(CA WA OR))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :west_coast, where(['st = ? or st = ? or st = ?'], "CA", "WA", "OR")
```